# Android Scrollview change Position (Scroll Down) When Spinner Spinner Selected

Tags: android, scroll, android-spinner

When I put spinner inside ScrollView I have an issue

After user select an item of ScrollView, ScrollView Scroll Down

Select item Of Spinner:

```
spn_cat_one.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int innerPosition, long l) {
            // ...
            spn_cat_one.clearFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    });
```

ScrollView OnTouchListener:

```
    scr_purchase_holder.requestFocusFromTouch();
        scr_purchase_holder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(spn_cat_one.hasFocus()){
                spn_cat_one.clearFocus();
            }
            scr_purchase_holder.requestFocusFromTouch();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And in xml, ScrollView Has Property:

```
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried almost all parameter combination (`android:focusable, android:focusableInTouchMode, android:descendantFocusability`...) but none of them worked for me.

Once the focus is on an `EditText`, the view will scroll to it after spinner selection change.
My solution was to implement the `OnTouchListener` of my spinners to clear focus on `EditText` and here it is:

Declare your listener as a field.

```
private View.OnTouchListener spinnerTouchListener;
```

Instantiate it before you set the listener to your spinners.

```
private void initListeners() {
//region spinnerTouchListener
    spinnerTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                View focused = getView().findFocus();
                if (focused instanceof EditText){
                    focused.clearFocus();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    //endregion
}
```

And set it to every spinner.

```
private void initSpinner() {
    mySpinner.setOnTouchListener(spinnerTouchListener)
    otherSpinner.setOnTouchListener(spinnerTouchListener)
}
```

It worked for me.

Enjoy

Comment: This is the perfect solution that I found after many hours of research. I recommend that you should copy this answer to many other similar questions in StackOverflow. Please check the list here - https://www.google.com/search?q=scrollview+scrolling+to+edittext+when+clicking+spinner+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hi @VishnuHaridas. Thanks for your comment. I will suggest my answer to other similar posts.